# How to get whole log info?

Tags: systemctl

To get the upload service's log info.

```
sudo journalctl -l  -u upload
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-01-18 22:38:54 EST, end at Fri 2018-04-13 23:44:37 EDT. --
Apr 13 23:36:50 localhost systemd[1]: Started upload files into dropbox.
Apr 13 23:36:50 localhost systemd[1]: Starting upload files into dropbox...
Apr 13 23:36:50 localhost bash[120]: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Apr 13 23:36:50 localhost bash[120]: Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Apr 13 23:36:50 localhost bash[120]: 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: content.dropboxapi.com; Un
Apr 13 23:36:50 localhost systemd[1]: upload.service: control process exited, code=exited status=6
```

For the 6th line,at the end of it ,it is `Could not resolve host: content.dropboxapi.com; Un` ,it is not a whole line,how can i get the characters behind `Un`?
How to get whole log info?

Comment: It wasn't logged. Try running the command yourself.

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229188/journalctl-how-to-prevent-text-from-truncating-in-terminal